# Use AirPods with the Vonage Phone service on my Mac

Tags: macos, airpods

I use the Vonage service to make calls from my MacBook Pro for business, both outgoing and incoming. My Mac shows the AirPods as connected but if I try to make a call, the sound still comes out of the internal speaker on my Mac.

Does anyone kn ow how I might fix this? Perhaps I need to adjust the internal microphone somehow?

I've already set the AirPods as both the Input and Output for sound.

Comment: Vonage doesn't make phones; they provide a *service*.   Please expand with additional details because as written, it's impossible to tell what you're trying to do with what exactly.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I use the service to make calls from my MacBook Pro for business, both outgoing and incoming. My Mac shows the AirPods as connected but if I try to make a call, the sound still comes out of the internal speaker on my computer. I have set the AirPods for the Input and Output for sound. Do I need to adjust the internal microphone? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the Vonage app (I don't even know if there is one) have a setting that allows you to select the microphone?  Skype does, for example.  Most VoIP apps I've seen does this.

Comment: Yes, I am using the Vonage app. I will check it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the EXACT same problem here. Was thinking to get Jabra headphones, or get a desk phone. Did you manage to sort this?

Comment: @JoeReeves Send me a comment if you choose to open a new question. We would need to know from where you got the Vonage software and perhaps what version you’re running

Answer (score 1):

If the headphones work with FaceTime and other audio apps then you can conclude the program you’re using for Vonage need some set up or you need to find a different program that respects the capabilities of macos to switch between multiple sound in and out options.

You have done all you can by using the sound preference pane to select a  choice and it’s up to the third-party software to respect your choices.